# Where can I find geodata on residential building footprint in US (or Texas)?

Tags: data-request, usa

Where can I find Texas residential building footprint data with information on **building area and number of floors**?

I came across National Structural Inventory github repo (https://github.com/HydrologicEngineeringCenter/NSI) which only contains data description. Does anyone know how I can download the data?

Comment: Have you looked at the [other building footprint data request questions](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=building+footprint) on this site? It looks like at least one of them has an answer.

Comment: @csk thanks. I had checked all related questions on this website. Just to be sure, I went back again and checked. Most of the questions are about building footprint and elevation. Building footprint can be obtained from Microsoft open data. I'm specifically interested in the building area (total area including all floors) and the number of floors.

Comment: Wow, that National Structures Inventory is like Bigfoot: lots of people seem to believe it exists, but if you search for it all you find are references, never the real thing.

Comment: I found two different sets of software that seem to have the ability to download the National Structures Inventory dataset: [HEC-FIA](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-fia/3.0_downloads.aspx) from the Corps of Engineers, and [Hazus](https://www.fema.gov/flood-maps/products-tools/hazus) from FEMA. Maybe if you comb through the technical manuals they will tell you where the source data comes from, or you could try installing the software and see if you can use it to obtain the NSI dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:
[Microsoft Building Footprints](https://github.com/microsoft/USBuildingFootprints).

The linked GitHub has downloads for each state. Additionally, in my state, we have an agency that aggregates county submitted tax GIS data into one dataset for building footprints. I suppose the Texas is probably lagging behind in that department, among others.

The National Structures Inventory is restricted to USACE for the time being as it includes proprietary licensed data. This is why you can read about it, but not access the actual data. I understand that they are working on an open source version, but I do not know when it will be available and if it will be totally public or just to partner agencies.